# Getting started with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up React for the first time following the [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html). I created main.js and ran the various commands.  The last command gives me error:

```
To install React DOM and build your bundle with webpack:

$ npm install --save react react-dom babel-preset-react
$ webpack
```

When I run `webpack` I receive error:

> Output filename not configured

It points me to the [usage docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html).  The usage docs tells me the command line interface expects input of the form:

```
webpack <entry> <output>
```

Obviously the command `webpack` as shown in the react tutorial does not meet this criteria.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you add your `webpack.config.js` file to this post? It sounds like you have not given the webpack configuration an output filename.

Comment: @AndyNoelker - This file does not exist.  Perhaps one of the previous steps failed?

Comment: Alright, the React tutorial you linked to is not a webpack tutorial. It even says to use gulp or webpack, so it's not showing you any steps to set up webpack - it assumes you already understand how to use module bundlers/task runners. I'd suggest checking out some beginner webpack tutorials. You'll need to create a `webpack.config.js` file yourself. You can see a basic example of one near the bottom of this link: https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/

Comment: However that tutorial also has a downloadable starter kit with all of the bundled files you'd need if you're not comfortable yet with using npm or webpack. So you could always use that to at least learn the basics of React.

Comment: @AndyNoelker - I'm a bit confused.  Webpack seems to generate as its output a file called "bundle.js".  I DO have a file called "bundle.js" and it is populated with 19k lines of code beginning with `require('react');`.  Yet, no `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: Well as you saw in your post, you do not HAVE to have a config file - you can manually bundle everything from the command line if you add an entry and output path to the command (i.e. `webpack ./myapp.js bundle.js`) but that would be very tedious and as you add loaders and other config options your command would grow monstrously. So that's why you would want to create a config file, because then you could just run `webpack` and it would compile correctly. I'd say read that webpack tutorial I linked to before. Also I still suggest just using the bundled files and not worrying about webpack.

Comment: If you're newer to modern web javascript development there is a definite learning curve to understanding how the different module bundlers/task runners work and are configured (and webpack is the best imo) but it's just something you'll have to take the time to learn. But the webpack config stuff has nothing to do with using React so that's why I suggested using the pre-bundled files provided by the React tutorial.

Comment: Webpack is notorious for having terrible "beginner" documentation. `webpack.config.js` is a file the _develop_ creates and providers, it is not generated automatically.

Comment: I found this Pluralsight course to be a far better introduction to React than the docs: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-flux-building-applications/table-of-contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *webpack.config.js*, eg.:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",
  entry: {
    jsx: './main.js',
    html: './index.html'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
}
```